# MongoDB load() output to mongodb commandline session

Tags: javascript, mongodb, load

I'm using MongoDB from the command line on a linux box.

I've written a simple deletedata.js script that looks like;

```
 //this script deletes everything
db.Collection1.deleteMany({})
db.Collection2.deleteMany({})
db.CollectionN+1.deleteMany({})
```

...to delete all the data form multiple collections in one go. I run it by I manually login to the Mongodb using the standard login command of;

```
mongo 'hostname'/mongodb_name --username myusername --password mypassword
```

...once I'm logged the mongoDb I can run the script using the mongoDb command;

```
load('/home/username/deletedata.js')
```

...this works fine and all the deleteMany commands run. However the only output I get from this script is; "true"

I'm okay with writing MongoDB commands but that's about it - I was wondering if I could update the script with more MongoDB commands and have output display within the mongoDB session I'm in at the commandline?

For example, I tried adding a line to get a count() i.e;

```
db.Collection1.find({}).count()
```

...but when I run;

```
load('/home/username/deletedata.js')
```

...all I get is "true" returned - how do I display the output from the count() command when it's in the .js and the .js is run from within MongoDB using load()?

I was expecting the result form the mongodb .count() command to output to the mongoDb command line, but the only output I get from using mongoDb load('') command is "true" if the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ret = db.Collection1.deleteMany({})
print(ret)
// or 
print(tojsononeline(ret))

var c = db.Collection1.find({}).count()
print(c)
```

If you use the new `mongosh` then you need to load [mongocompat](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongosh-snippets/tree/main/snippets/mongocompat) or use `print(EJSON.stringify(ret))`